# Apache Flink 1.6.0 - StateTtlConfig and ListState

Tags: events, apache-flink, ttl, stateful

I am in the process of implementing a proof-of-concept stream processing system using Apache Flink 1.6.0 and am storing a list of received events, partitioned by key, in a `ListState`.  (Don't worry about why I am doing this, just work with me here.)  I have a `StateTtlConfig` set on the corresponding `ListStateDescriptor`.  [Per the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl):

1. "All state collection types support per-entry TTLs. This means that list elements and map entries expire independently."
2. "Currently, expired values are only removed when they are read out explicitly, e.g. by calling `ValueState.value()`."

**Question 1**

Which of the following constitutes a read of the `ListState`:

1. Requesting the iterator but not using it - `myListState.get();`.
2. Actually using the iterator - `for (MyItem i : myListState.get()) { ... }`

**Question 2**

What does "per-entry TTL" *actually* mean?  Specifically, what I'm asking about is the following:

Assume I have a specific instance of `ListState<Character>`.  The descriptor has a TTL of 10 seconds.  I insert a `'a'`.  Two seconds later, I insert `'b'`.  Nine seconds later I insert `'c'`.  If I iterate over this `ListState`, which items will be returned?

In other words:

```
ListState<Character> ls = getRuntimeContext().getListState(myDescriptor);

ls.add('a');

// ...two seconds later...
ls.add('b');

// ...nine seconds later...
ls.add('c');

// Does this iterate over 'a', 'b', 'c'
// or just 'b' and 'c'?
for (Character myChar : ls.get()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1**

The answer is 1. For ListState the pruning is done for `myListState.get();`.

**Answer 2**

"per-entry TTL" means the timeout is applied to a single entry rather than whole collection. For your example assuming at the point of reading 10 seconds passed since inserting the a it will iterate over `b` and `c`. `a` is going to be pruned in this case.